# CakePHP - HABTM separate join table that also needs a HTBTM relationship

Tags: cakephp

Im creating a HTBTM relation like:

---

Dressess

---

id

name

---

Dressess_Styles

---

id

dress_id

style_id

---

Styles

---

id

name

---

Now i need the every Dresses_Styles also can Has and Belongs to Many Colors.

My question:

Some light and considerations on how do I create this relationships without breaking CakePHP standard.

Please tell me what you think about this:

---

Colors_Dressess_Styles

---

id

dress_style_id

color_id

---

Colors

---

id

name

It is the correct way or exist a better one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.

Dresses belongs to Dresses_Styles

Styles belongs to Dresses_Styles

Dresses_Styles HABTM Colors

Answer (score 0):

It's just my rule of thumb, but when I need to to actually create HABTM model (to add methods, relationships, etc.), it usually means that it is a separate model by itself. Does Dresses_Styles represent any entity here?